# Restart a new game+ in Mass Effect 1

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, mass-effect

So I have recently decided to replay the trilogy to flesh out some achievements and re-experience it before Andromeda comes out. I have a level 59 character I want to start a new file with and play through again. No issue there, I know how to normally choose the existing ID when creating a new game.

The issue is I started a play through with this character back in 2014 and never finished it, so there is a pre existing save with him, so I can't use that ID to start a new file. Or at least I can't seem to find out how if you can. I dare not delete the save file for fear of losing the character himself. Is there any way to make this work so I can restart a new game plus with that character, or am I stuck with a partial play through?

If it matters, it's on a XBox One via backwards compatibility.

Comment: my understanding is that you have to finish the game with that character before you can use it for any other play through.  So what I would recommend, finish the game with that character, then use it for the other MEs

Answer (score 1):

Characters are only available to start a new game with once you have completed the main story quests. This means you must complete the existing playthrough on your existing save before you can re-use it for a new playthrough.